How to load and pass data from JSON into child view controller?
I want to create a epub book reader app with custom page view controller instead default. I want to load data from JSON file and pass it into child view controller. But I have a problem: my data doesn't showing when I launch the project.
My ParentViewController:
private struct PagesData: Decodable {
    var pagesData: [PageData]
}

private struct PageData: Decodable {
    let textData, textPosition: String
}

class CustomPageViewController: UIViewController {

    private var pagesContent: [ContentViewController] = []
    private var pagesData = [PageData]()
    let contentViewController = ContentViewController()
    
    var pageNumber = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let childViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContentViewController")
        self.addChildViewController(childViewController)
        self.view.addSubview(childViewController.view)
        childViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        childViewController.view.frame = self.view.frame
        
        loadData()
    }
            
    func loadData() {
        
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "pages", withExtension: "json")!
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
        let result = try! JSONDecoder().decode(PagesData.self, from: data)
        
        for page in result.pagesData {
            let contentVC = ContentViewController()
            contentVC.configure(text: page.textData,
                                image: "image\(pagesContent.count).png",
                                position: page.textPosition)
            pagesContent.append(contentVC)
        }
    }

}

My ChildViewController:
class ContentViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var textPosition = "bottomLeft"
    
    private lazy var textLabel: UILabel = {
        
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textAlignment = .left
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.textColor = .white
        label.sizeToFit()
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25, weight: .bold)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        return label
        
    }()
    
    private lazy var imageView: UIImageView = {
        
        let image = UIImageView()
        image.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        image.backgroundColor = .gray
        
        return image
        
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setupViews()
        setupConstraints()
    }

    func configure(text: String, image: String, position: String) {
        textLabel.text = text
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: image)
        textPosition = position
    }
    
    private func setupViews() {
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        view.addSubview(textLabel)
    }
        
    private func setupConstraints() {
        
        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        
        switch textPosition {
        case "topCenter":
            
            textLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor,
                                           constant: 16).isActive = true
            textLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor,
                                               constant: 16).isActive = true
            textLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor,
                                                constant: -16).isActive = true
            
        case "centerCenter":
            
            textLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor,
                                               constant: 16).isActive = true
            textLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor,
                                                constant: -16).isActive = true
            textLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            textLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
            
        case "bottomCenter":
            
            textLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor,
                                              constant: -16).isActive = true
            textLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor,
                                               constant: 16).isActive = true
            textLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor,
                                                constant: -16).isActive = true
            
        case "topLeft":
            
            textLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor,
                                           constant: 16).isActive = true
            textLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor,
                                               constant: 16).isActive = true
            textLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor,
                                                constant: -16 - (view.frame.size.width/2)).isActive = true
            
        case "centerLeft":
            
            textLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor,
                                           constant: 16).isActive = true
            textLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor,
                                              constant: -16).isActive = true
            textLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor,
                                               constant: 16).isActive = true
            textLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor,
                                                constant: -16 - (view.frame.size.width/2)).isActive = true
            
        case "bottomLeft":
            
            textLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, 
                                              constant: -16).isActive = true
            textLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, 
                                               constant: 16).isActive = true
            textLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor,
                                                constant: -16 - (view.frame.size.width/2)).isActive = true
            
        case "topRight":
            
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor,
                                           constant: 0).isActive = true
            imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, 
                                               constant: 0).isActive = true
            imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, 
                                                constant: 0).isActive = true
            
        case "centerRight":
            
            textLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor,
                                           constant: 16).isActive = true
            textLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, 
                                              constant: -16).isActive = true
            textLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, 
                                               constant: 16 + (view.frame.size.width/2)).isActive = true
            textLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor,
                                                constant: -16).isActive = true
            
        case "bottomRight":
            
            textLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor,
                                              constant: -16).isActive = true
            textLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor,
                                               constant: 16 + (view.frame.size.width/2)).isActive = true
            textLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, 
                                                constant: -16).isActive = true
            
        default:
            
            textLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor,
                                              constant: -16).isActive = true
            textLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor,
                                               constant: 16).isActive = true
            textLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor,
                                                constant: -16).isActive = true
        }
    }

}

How to resolve the problem? And what I should fix in this project?
new info 1:
I can't understand what the problem is. If I run the following code in ChildViewController:
func configure(text: String, image: String, position: String) {

    textLabel.text = text
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: image)
    textPosition = position
        
    print(textLabel.text!)
}

I will see result from JSON in the debug.
Optional("1"), Optional("2"), Optional("3"), Optional("4")
But the app screen will be blank.
If I use this code  textLabel.text = "text"
func configure(text: String, image: String, position: String) {
    textLabel.text = "text"
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: image)
    textPosition = position
}

I can see "text" in my label...
Also I trying to use my code in UIPageViewController. To check json file. All works fine. But this code doesn't work in ParentViewController:
new info 2:
code in PageViewController:
import UIKit

private struct PagesData: Decodable {
    var pagesData: [PageData]
}

private struct PageData: Decodable {
    let textData, textPosition: String
}

class PageViewController: UIPageViewController {

    var pagesContent: [ContentViewController] = []
    private var pagesData = [PageData]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.dataSource = self
        loadData()
    }
    
    func loadData() {
        
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "pages", withExtension: "json")!
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
        let result = try! JSONDecoder().decode(PagesData.self, from: data)
        
        for page in result.pagesData {
            let contentVC = ContentViewController()
            contentVC.configure(text: page.textData,
                                image: "image\(pagesContent.count).png",
                                position: page.textPosition)
            pagesContent.append(contentVC)
        }
        
        if let firstPage = pagesContent.first {
            setViewControllers([firstPage], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

}

// MARK: - Extension

extension PageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
  
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let contentVC = viewController as? ContentViewController,
              let currentIndex = pagesContent.firstIndex(of: contentVC),
              currentIndex > 0 else {
            return nil
        }
        return pagesContent[currentIndex - 1]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let contentVC = viewController as? ContentViewController,
              let currentIndex = pagesContent.firstIndex(of: contentVC),
              currentIndex < pagesContent.count - 1 else {
            return nil
        }
        return pagesContent[currentIndex + 1]
    }
}


Can you elaborate on your problem, like where exactly you are facing the issue? Is your JSON serialization is getting failed or second view controller is not launching?

I add new info in question after some info: title.  Can this code help you? The data from the json is loaded into the project and loaded in the label, but it is not displayed in the app.

As you added the result from JSON decoding, I can see you are only getting one property (I guess it is textPosition)but you should be getting two because you have textData, textPosition in your model. You need to check your JSON model to see if there are any issues with it. The problem is with the JSON-to-model conversation.

@Pratik I add my code in UIPageViewController. Add code to question in "new info 2" title. All works fine. Why code from custom parent controller doesn't work? Also if I use this code print(textLabel), print(textPosition)in child controller I get all field from my json in debug

@Pratik I can't figure out why the data isn't showing on the screen. Although they are transferred to child

Ohh, I guess that your viewDidLoad() is getting called after your configure() method, which is causing the problem. Can you check if this is the case?

@Pratik I check it with using breakpoint. viewDidLoad() was firs

In CustomPageViewController -> viewDidLoad(), you are instantiating a "ContentViewController" from Storyboard and adding its view. Then, in loadData(), you are creating numerous instances of ContentViewController -- not from Storyboard, and appending them to an array. But that's all you do. How do you expect the contents (views) from the controllers in the array to get to the screen?

@DonMag now I use let childViewController = ContentViewController() instead storyboard. But how I can show controllers on the screen? As I know in PageViewController I have setViewControllers method. Does this method load the controller from an array on the screen?

@user - you really, really, really need to do some in-depth research on the basics. There is absolutely no reason to create an array of 100s of view controllers, each containing simple labels. Use one UIView subclass, and re-use it. You may want to search for swift ebook reader sample code -- you might find something already suitable for use, or at least close enough that you can modify it to suit your needs.

@DonMag Do you really think that I first write a question on stackoverflow and am so lazy to search info on the web? Of course, I first search on web. And I explained to you that there are no examples that use your tips, like CATransition. For example, folioreaderkit uses UICollectionViewCell and each cell as a page. I've looked through it all. There are no simple examples or complex ones either. This topic is of little interest to anyone. And only in this case I decided to resort to the help of the pros on stackoverflow.

@DonMag Of course now there is no point in creating an array of view controllers but in the future I will have more code in the controllers. Not just simple labels. Ok. Can be replaced with an array from uiview. Not sure if this is better. As a result for my app. Could you please explain specifically in the code what I'm doing wrong in this question? Because "you may want to search for swift ebook reader sample code" doesn't help me. If you remember, more weeks have passed between this and the previous question.

@DonMag  And I really studied how you created, searched on forums and everywhere. Could you show an example of how you see such an app using uiview instead controllers?

Let's see if this can help get you on your way...
We'll start with a simple data struct:
struct SimplePageData {
    var pageText: String = ""
    var pageImageName: String = ""
    var bkgColor: UIColor = .systemRed
}

Next, we'll create a UIView subclass that will be the "page content view" -- it has a UIImageView that fills the view, and a UILabel inset by 16-points:
class MySimpleContentView: UIView {
    
    private let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let v = UIImageView()
        v.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        v.backgroundColor = .darkGray
        v.tintColor = .gray
        return v
    }()
    
    private let theLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 48.0, weight: .bold)
        v.textColor = .white
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        return v
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
    
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(imageView)
        theLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(theLabel)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // image view constrained at Zero to all 4 sides
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // label constrained to all 4 sides, inset by 16-points
            theLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            theLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            theLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0),
            theLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -16.0),
        ])
        
    }
    
    func configure(theData: SimplePageData) {
        theLabel.text = theData.pageText
        if let img = UIImage(named: theData.pageImageName) {
            imageView.image = img
        } else if let img = UIImage(systemName: theData.pageImageName) {
            imageView.image = img
        }
        imageView.backgroundColor = theData.bkgColor
    }
    
}

The basic idea will be:

create a "container" view
add two instances of MySimpleContentView as subviews of the container
to create a "page," we call configure() and fill in the image and text
to "show" a page, we hide the current visible page view and show the newly-configured page view

So, our basic view controller will be this:
class SampleViewVC: UIViewController {
    
    let myPagesData: [SimplePageData] = [
        SimplePageData(pageText: "This is the\n\nFirst Page", pageImageName: "swift", bkgColor: .systemRed),
        SimplePageData(pageText: "Here is the\n\nSecond Page", pageImageName: "apple.logo", bkgColor: .systemGreen),
        SimplePageData(pageText: "And now, let's show the Third and final Page", pageImageName: "desktopcomputer", bkgColor: .systemBlue),
    ]
    
    var pgIndex: Int = 0
    
    // this will hold the page views
    let pageContainer: UIView = UIView()
    
    // two page views
    let pageViews: [MySimpleContentView] = [
        MySimpleContentView(),
        MySimpleContentView(),
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        [pageContainer, pageViews[0], pageViews[1]].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        
        // add the "page views" to the container view
        pageContainer.addSubview(pageViews[0])
        pageContainer.addSubview(pageViews[1])
        
        view.addSubview(pageContainer)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            pageContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            pageContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            pageContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            pageContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
            // constrain both page views to all 4 sides of the container view
            pageViews[0].topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pageContainer.topAnchor),
            pageViews[0].leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pageContainer.leadingAnchor),
            pageViews[0].trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pageContainer.trailingAnchor),
            pageViews[0].bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pageContainer.bottomAnchor),
            
            pageViews[1].topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pageContainer.topAnchor),
            pageViews[1].leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pageContainer.leadingAnchor),
            pageViews[1].trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pageContainer.trailingAnchor),
            pageViews[1].bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pageContainer.bottomAnchor),
        ])
        
        // so we can see the container frame
        pageContainer.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        pageContainer.layer.borderWidth = 1

        // show the first page
        pgIndex = -1
        nextPage(animated: false)
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        // for this example, tap anywhere to go to the next page
        nextPage(animated: true)
    }
    
    func nextPage(animated: Bool) {

        pgIndex += 1
        if pgIndex == myPagesData.count {
            pgIndex = 0
        }
        
        // fromView is the one that is NOT hidden
        let fromView = pageViews[0].isHidden ? pageViews[1] : pageViews[0]
        
        // toView is the one that IS hidden
        let toView = pageViews[0].isHidden ? pageViews[0] : pageViews[1]
        
        // fill the toView with the next page's data
        toView.configure(theData: myPagesData[pgIndex])

        showNextPage(fromView: fromView, toView: toView)

        // we'll implement the animation in the next step
    }

    func showNextPage(fromView: UIView, toView: UIView) {
        // hide the fromView
        fromView.isHidden = true
        // show the toView
        toView.isHidden = false
    }
    
}

When run, it will look like this - each tap (anywhere) will display the "next page":
  
To add transitions, we'll make a couple changes...
The nextPage() func becomes:
func nextPage(animated: Bool) {
    
    pgIndex += 1
    if pgIndex == myPagesData.count {
        pgIndex = 0
    }
    
    // fromView is the one that is NOT hidden
    let fromView = pageViews[0].isHidden ? pageViews[1] : pageViews[0]
    
    // toView is the one that IS hidden
    let toView = pageViews[0].isHidden ? pageViews[0] : pageViews[1]
    
    // fill the toView with the next page's data
    toView.configure(theData: myPagesData[pgIndex])
    
    if animated {
        animateNextPage(fromView: fromView, toView: toView)
    } else {
        showNextPage(fromView: fromView, toView: toView)
    }
}

No change to showNextPage():
func showNextPage(fromView: UIView, toView: UIView) {
    // hide the fromView
    fromView.isHidden = true
    // show the toView
    toView.isHidden = false
}

and here is our animateNextPage() function:
func animateNextPage(fromView: UIView, toView: UIView) {
    
    // show the toView
    toView.isHidden = false
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
        let animation = CATransition()
        animation.duration = 1.0
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
        
        // various animation types
        //  note that for pageCurl, we have to use the "rawValue" format
        animation.type = CATransitionType(rawValue: "pageCurl")
        //animation.type = .fade
        //animation.type = .moveIn
        //animation.type = .push
        //animation.type = .reveal
        
        animation.subtype = CATransitionSubtype(rawValue: "fromRight")
        animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = true
        
        // perform the transition animation
        //  this will animate and hide the fromView
        self.pageContainer.layer.add(animation, forKey: "pageAnimation")
        
        // bring the toView to the front
        self.pageContainer.bringSubviewToFront(toView)
    })
    
}

Now, on tapping anywhere, instead of just "seeing the next page" we will get an animation to the next page.
Un-comment the different animation.type lines to see the various "built-in" transitions.

There will be a LOT more to do...
If you want to implement continuous scrolling, you may want to replace the "container" view with a collection view -- on-the-fly.
To make interactive page-curl transition easier, you may want to replace the "container" view with a UIPageViewController -- again, on-the-fly.
You might also want to implement other animated transitions. There is a wealth of information available - including articles, blog posts, example code, etc - out there showing all sorts of different animation techniques.
